# Rails - uninitialised constant AdminUser with ActiveAdmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm new in Rails and I'll try to install ActiveAdmin to my existing project (Rails 3.2.1).

i've had activeadmin, meta_search, devise and sass-rails in my gemfile. Require devise in the configuration/application.rb.

When I try to run "rails generate active_admin:install" or "rails server", i have an error :

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/l
ive_support/inflector/methods
connstant AdminUser (NameError)

I dont know how to fix.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Did you accidentally write those typos in your NameError? Or is that how it was returned?

Comment: In fact, I didn't modify anything. I follow this tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/) and I block in the first step with this error...!

Comment: Hi,in your gem file you have gem "activeadmin", so replace that with following line and try   gem "activeadmin", :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"

Comment: Thanks, I did it, `bundle install`, new things was installed but after, there is the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the following line on `routes.rb`

`devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config`

Then rerun

`rails g active_admin:install`

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error after uninstalling and resintalling activeadmin (as I wanted to remove it from admin_user to install it in my own user).

Solution was to search through my project for "admin", and comment all the code that activeadmin had left after uninstall.

The files where I found activeadmin code were:

```
routes.rb
schema.rb
```